# EntityFramework query

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I have problem with EntityFramework querying. Suppose i have two entities: master and child. In child entity i have field (int)SNumber. Now i want query max number from childs:

```
 labelMaxSNumber.text = (_context.Child.Select(s => s.SNumber)).Max();
```

This works normally on gui, but i want create this in DataModel:

```
labelMaxSNumber.text = _context.GetMaxSNumber();
```

I don't know where post this code: in ObjectContext partial class or in EntityObject partial class?

Comment: ??? is it so hard to at least complete your question? Btw. this is server side code.

Comment: Ladislav, sorry, i did't noticed that i'm not complete code. How can i query childs on client side?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. What is client and server side?

Comment: client side - gui, server side - data model.

Comment: And what is your client side? Is it in the same process as data model?

Comment: yes, now i have this code: myLabel.Text =  (_context.Child.Select(s => s.SNumber)).Max(). But i want create method in datamodel, something like this: myLabel.Text = _context.GetMaxSNumber(). Is it possible?

Comment: Edit your question to add details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Simply create partial class for your context and add method:

```
public partial class YourContextName
{
    public int GetMaxSNumber()
    {
        return this.Child.Max(c => c.SNumber);
    }
}
```